How to enforce an arc $(a,b)=1$ in branch and price algorithm?
I am trying to solve a vehicle routing problem using a branch and price algorithm. At the restricted master problem (RMP), we consider two branches: we enforce an arc $(a,b)$=0 and  $(a,b)$=1 (I am following the method described in here page 41). $(a,b)$=0 can be enforced pretty easily, but I am facing difficulty in enforcing $(a,b)$=1. This is because my solution in the RMP sometimes looks like this:
[x,y,z,a,b] = 0.5
[z,a,b,x,y] = 0.5
That is, I don't get a single path involving $(a,b)$=1, I get multiple paths involving $(a,b)$ as fractional values summing to 1, which is not what I intended. I tried formulating the RMP differently using penalty method (if $(a,b)$ is used more than once, we penalize) and using the routes involving $(a,b)$ as integer variables that sum to 1. But on both occasions the RMP does not stay a LP, which is essential because I need the dual variables from the RMP to calculate the reduced cost in the subproblem and enter newly generated routes into the master problem.

The last sentence on page 41 specifies what to do.  To branch up on arc $(i,j)$, you remove all arcs out of $i$ other than $(i,j)$ and all arcs into $j$ other than $(i,j)$.  You should solve the subproblem with integer variables.  The dual variables come from the master problem, not the subproblem.

I am sorry I mixed up master and subproblems. Could you please reread my question description?

The paper suggests branching in the subproblem instead of in the master.  Indeed, the arc variables appear only in the subproblem and not in the master.

if i am not wrong, it is possible to apply branching on either master or subproblem. Even if I do the branching on the subproblem, the problem that I am facing will still remain. There may be more than one eligible routes (like those I mentioned above) that will be added into the master problem, and we might end up with fractional results like before.

If you enforce integrality in the subproblem, you will not get fractional solutions in the subproblem.
